# How to get data out of running application from non-rooted phone

Tags: android

I'am writing some small security report about Android devices in general related to accessing information from RAM. 
Main condition is that device initially is non-rooted.

Use case:
User opens 3rd-party app, enters some password in password field. After that the device is lost with this running application. Source code of this application shows that this password information available in RAM while application is up and running. For example in class AllMyAppPasswords in public String myPassword. Now is the question about possible way to access this password info (correct me if I am wrong):

1. The way to access this pwd is to dump the memory.
2. For memory dump I need to have device to be rooted.
3. In order to root the device I need to unlock bootloader.
4. To achieve unlock bootloader and root operations it is requires that device needs to be rebooted at least once.
5. After device is rebooted the information about password is gone from RAM

Conclusion: It is not possible to get password residing in RAM memory from app if device is non-rooted. Is it correct?

Update to use case:
We assume that user just un-boxed new device and 100% sure that it is not rooted and not contain any keylogger apps. So user just installed my app, entered password, and application uses this password internally during run-time for periodically connecting the server (password only RAM, never stored on disk). So, visually there is nothing left in Edit text fields, info about password only in application memory for internal use, of course it is not possible just to read password text from the screen. Now user lost his phone. Should user concern about someone who found his phone can get this password info from RAM?

Comment: I am regret that my question is closed. So far I cannot get anywhere else professional answers about and around Android software development and related subjects. I understand that my question is not directly related to coding, but it is about issue that directly related to how I should code in order to protect my application data.

Comment: I think such a user would have numerous other problems to worry about. That said, sure; they may need to worry about that. But as per the closing; this question is off-topic, as you don't present an immediate coding problem you are dealing with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not being a hands-on insider in this area, I will claim that I'm certainly interested above average, and here are my thoughts. Not meaning to say you don't potentially already know this, though.

- Yes, Linux protects process memory from other regular users (with root not being a regular user).
- I don't see why in the scenario you describe, the person who finds the phone would not simply bring the app in question to the foreground and have all confidetial information displayed, because your scenario already assumes that whoever finds the device can successfully unlock it, and that the app is still running.
- I am however suspecting (inspired by your hypothetical *AllMyAppPasswords* class) that you are intending to build an argument similar to the following: *If my "password safe" app starts and identifies that the device is not rooted, a reboot is required to change this fact, and since on a non-rooted device there is no way to access my app's memory, holding decrypted confidential information in RAM is safe*. If this is along the lines of your intended rationale, I'd like to point your attention to the following aspects.

  - It is relatively easy to reverse engineer your code from your APK even if you apply a byte code obfuscator. This is especially true if someone out there decides that confidential information held in your app's memory is important enough for them. This means that everyone can relatively easy figure what to look for, once they gain access.
  - There *are* security holes both in Linux and in Java Virtual Machines, and the update strategy of the Android device vendors is not exactly transparent in this respect. In other words, there may be a way, direct or by combination of bugs, to either execute code in root context or with the user ID of your app even if the phone is not rooted.
  - Ways to root phones may change once your app has been published, so you may not be able to reliably identify a rooted phone.
  - Any encrypted data and the key must solely exist on a trusted server, or otherwise people will simply extract the key from your app and access the encrypted data stored on the Android device (if any) instead of trying to access app RAM.
- All bets are off if someone has an Android device which allows for an in-circuit debugger to be connected, which would then theoretically allow for direct memory access without any software being aware of this. I'm not sure about the exact prerequisites for such a scenario and I also don't know which precautions individual manufacturers take in this respect.

I have somewhat widened the scope of your original question, but maybe there's still something useful in it for you. Even when sticking to your question word by word, I believe the *security hole* point really hurts, besides the fact that I'm unaware of any reliable (fully doubt-free, now and in future) way to identify a rooted device.

Direct hardware access may be out of scope for the security level you aim at or not, but I seem to recall that I read something about this recently.

Comment: Very informative. Thank you!

Comment: About use case: I just added extra details about situation that could happen in real life.